# find_all only scrape the last value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website and I am using find_all but it only returns the last div in the page and ignores the other two! Any idea?

Here is the inspected source by chrome inspector:

```html
<div id="listDesc" class="pane show pane"> ... <div> ==$0
<p> ... </p>
<p> ... </p>
<div id="listDesc" class="pane show pane"> ... <div>
<p> ... </p>
<p> ... </p>
<p> ... </p>
<div id="listDesc" class="pane show pane"> ... <div>
<p> ... </p>
<p> ... </p>
```

I have checked the website's source code and I only found only one div with the same name:

```html
<div id="listDesc" class="pane showpane">
```

I have tried different approaches to scrape div(s)  separately, though that did not work too! Here is the code that I am using.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

source_ = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_, 'lxml')

for match in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'pane showpane'}):
    print(match.text) # This prints only the last div
```

How can I get the content of all three div?

Comment: giving multiple tags the same `id="listDesc"` is wrong semantics

Comment: Without looking at the website it is pretty hard to help you. I am going to guess `javascript` is involved here.

Comment: what is the link?

Comment: please provide the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by looping through id:

```
    for match in soup.find_all('div', id="listDesc"):
        print(match.text)
```